# Help identify circa 1970s animated movie with bizarre wedding

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I remember a movie from my childhood that was based on a common folk tale. It was in a very odd animation style (though I cannot remember which). The strongest memory was that there was a very strange wedding with a fairly scary song and the guests were something like wavering creatures enchanted by an evil witch. The wedding was between "A princess?" and some kind of huge and ugly ogre.

I strongly remember talking to many friends about the film so it had a fairly good 'release' but I don't seem to have enough strong memories to hang it off of. The multitude of symbols makes it difficult to remember which folk tale it was. The vagueness of the terms haven't turned up anything in attempts to google search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would appear that this film is an Anime variant of [Jack and the Beanstalk](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074705/) (orig: "[Jakku to Mame no Ki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_the_Beanstalk_%281974_film%29)" from 1974 (released in the US in 1976).

The Ogre was the Giant who was the child/stepson of a witch. He grew larger fueled by anger towards the end. The wedding guests are paper-cutouts which are animated by the witch. The wedding is scored with a very haunting (Elfmanesque) song called (in the English version) "Are you Happy". The [video of the scene in Japanese](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYnmzE3azdk) is available on YouTube. The [audio of the English version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvkfXICMXBk) is also on YouTube.

The film can (as of this posting) be seen in [its entirety on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnd3MFBink4).

Comment: Thank you greatly to Nobby who gave me the link to the information. Seeing the DVD cover on IMDB promptly was like a veil lifting.

Comment: A result is a result - happy to help ;)

Answer (score 3):

Might you be thinking of the BBC production, *[The Light Princess](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0229533/)* (1978)?

The only criteria it meets is a fairly odd animation style and a princess.

Comment: I looked at the link on IMDB. It wasn't correct, but the section "Users that liked this also liked" actually contained the answer which I'll post. Thanks for the connection.